# LMA - unable to login on Subscriber org

Tags: managed-package, subscriber, lma

Are you aware of any issue or new restriction introduced recently to log on Subscriber?

I granted access to our company, logged out, and then logged in our LMA, then I opened the Subscriber using the org id, but then it shows no entry to log-in.

Is this a Salesforce issue that might be happening?

I am asking because a few days ago I used the exact same feature ([Log In to Subscriber Orgs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm&type=5)) and it worked, for the same org, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this wasn't working since I had LMA installed in Developer Edition org. When I requested for PBO and used LMA there, this option has appeared.

Documentation says that [Log In to Subscriber Orgs works only in Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
Editions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm&type=5)